# Why does view appear partially?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I try to add view to another view from another thread,but it displays partially. But after I clicked on it view,all become alright.
Look at this: [was](http://postimage.org/image/839c7470v/) and [become](http://postimage.org/image/du0hb67dt/).

I add view this way:

```
SecretWordsFormView *swfv = [[SecretWordsFormView alloc] 
    initWithFrame:vc.view.frame 
    positions:positions 
    logonFormCtl:ctl 
    parent:parent poscount:numberOf];

[vc.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:swfv waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Why does this happen? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange but after I replace

```
[vc.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:swfv waitUntilDone:YES];
```

to this

```
[vc.view addSubview:swfv];
```

Now full view appears normally.

I don't know why this strange thing happend.

Comment: Were you in a background thread when you were calling the method?  Otherwise there's no need to specifically call on the main thread.

Comment: Obviously didn't,but I thought that.

Comment: "there's no need" - yes, but if I call method `performOnMainThread...` on main thread, did not the method implement the same way as simple call of `addSubview:` ?

Comment: No, they're the same.  But unless you're not sure you're going to be running on the main thread, then there's no need to use `performSelectorOnMainThread::`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `setNeedsDisplay`?